# How to create Unique key for a varchar column for entity framework database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, unique

I had watch youtube video tutorial teaching how to create unique key

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oqrsfatxTYE&list=PL08903FB7ACA1C2FB&index=9

In the video, he has created a unique key for Email(nvarchar) column, I could create it when I create database manually, but when I try create unique key for a database created with entity framework code first, using the next query

```
ALTER  TABLE Peoples
   ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_MyTable_Email UNIQUE (email)
```

It will generate a error:

```
Msg 1919, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Column 'email' in table 'Peoples' is of a type that is invalid for use as a key column in an index.
```

What is problem? what can I do for create unique key for nvarchar(max) column?

Comment: What is the data length for you Email conlumn ??

Comment: is a nvarchar(max) column

Comment: here you go, 1st of all you cannot create any idexes on a VARCHAR(MAX) columns, when you create a Unique constraint it actually create a non-clustered Unique index behind the scenes. you need to change your datatype and see my answer for more details.

Comment: why would you use VARCHAR(MAX) for email column ??? just use varchar 100-200 something like that personally I have never seen an email longer then say 50 characters :)

Comment: Because I'm using Code First, when I not specify how length is column, it will create with Max. I changed type for NVARCHAR(50), and I add Unique constraint successes, Thank you so much!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

say If you create this table

```
CREATE TABLE ConstTable 
(ID INT, 
Email VARCHAR(1000)
CONSTRAINT uc_Email UNIQUE (Email)
)
GO
```

you will get a warning :

> Warning! The maximum key length is 900 bytes. The index 'uc_Email' has
>   maximum length of 1000 bytes. For some combination of large values,
>   the insert/update operation will fail

Your column on which you want to define a unique constraint should be less then or equal to 900 bytes, so you can have a `VARCHAR(900)` or `NVARCHAR(450)` column if you want to be able to create a unique constraint on that column

Same table above with VARCHAR(450) gets created without any warning

```
CREATE TABLE ConstTable 
(ID INT, 
Email VARCHAR(900)
CONSTRAINT uc_Email UNIQUE (Email)
)
GO
```

**Result**

> Command(s) completed successfully.

**Test For your Table**

say this is your table

```
CREATE TABLE ConstTable 
(ID INT, 
Email VARCHAR(MAX)
)
GO
```

Now try to create any index on the VARCHAR(MAX) data type and you will get the same error.

```
CREATE INDEX ix_SomeIdex
ON ConstTable (Email)
```

**Error Message**

> Msg 1919, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Column 'Email' in table
>   'ConstTable' is of a type that is invalid for use as a key column in
>   an index.